# Get URL for file in content

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My problem is pretty simple, Razer don't render right path to files in Content dictionary. Here is example how I want to render logo:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/assets/img/logo_white.png")" 
     alt="logo" class="brand" 
     data-src="@Url.Content("~/Content/assets/img/logo_white.png")" 
     data-src-retina="@Url.Content("~/Content/assets/img/logo_white_2x.png")" 
     width="93" height="25">
```

But razer output is just "assets/img/logo_white.png" without Content at begining and right path is "Content/assets/img/logo_white.png".

Where is problem? It seems to me like a bug, but maybe I miss something.

Comment: Does removing ~/ help a bit?!

Comment: @YoupTube unfortunately not.

Comment: Is Content a c# / .NET reserved word that gets removed in some way? Can you try to put your images somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after simplify template image was sucesfully rendered, so somewhere something crash. Now I'll move by little steps and try to fix problem. Ty 4 your time.

Answer (score -1):

Does it work this way?

```
src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Content/assets/img/{0}", "logo_white.png"))"
```

It does in my code. But also have to say that without the String format it produces the right location / path in some demo code of mine, whereas in your situation it doesn't for some strange reason...

Comment: Thank you for help, but it's probably some kind of bug, neither this workaround doesn't work